# What is a transcedental Equation?

Tags: transcendental-equations

I was studying equations, and came across the term Transcedental being use for equations of the form,
$$ \sin(x) -e^{x} + x^{2 }= 0 $$
From what I understand, the equations involving terms like exp, sin are called transcedental. I also googled and found that  equations of the form  $\space a_{n}x^{n} + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} ... + a_{0} = 0 \space$ (the lhs is a polynomial) are called algebraic.
Finally, then what are equations of the form $ \space x^{\frac{3}{2}} - 2x + x^{\frac{5}{3}} = 0 \space $ called?

**NOTE**: These are just random examples.

Comment: If i substitute $x = y^6$, then it becomes a polynomial $y^9-2y^6+y^10 = $, question: is $sin()$ transcendental or algebraic

Comment: @AderinsolaJoshua and how would that work?

Comment: @LordCommander what are you referring to

Comment: @AderinsolaJoshua i was wondering how you tirned the $e^x$ into an $x^a$

Answer (score 1):

A transcendental equation is an equation that is not algebraic.  The equation $x^{\frac{3}{2}} - 2x + x^{\frac{5}{3}} = 0$ is algebraic, since its solutions are solutions of some polynomial equation (which takes some manipulation to find).